Can any matrix be decomposed into the product of a symmetric matrix and another matrix?
For any matrix $X\in\mathbb R^{m\times n}(m\leq n)$ that has full rank, i.e. $rank(X)=m$,
can we find 2 matrices $Y\in\mathbb R^{m\times m}$ and $Z\in\mathbb R^{m\times n}$,
s.t. $X=YZ$, $\enspace rank(Y)=rank(Z)=m\enspace$ and $\enspace Y$ is symmetric but not a diagonal matrix?
(I emphasize $Y$ is not diagonal to exclude trivial cases)

I notice, in LU factorization, $X$ can be decomposed into a lower triangular matrix $L\in\mathbb R^{m\times m}$ and upper triangular matrix $U\in\mathbb R^{m\times n}$ s.t. $X=LU$;
If there exists some invertible matrix $P\in\mathbb R^{m\times m}$ s.t. $LP^{-1}=Y$ ($Y$ is symmetic but not diagonal), then I get $Z=PU$ and the problem is solved.
So the question can be rewritten as:
Can any full-rank lower trigular matrix $L\in\mathbb R^{m\times m}$ be transformed to a symmetric matrix via only elementary column transformations?
I think this can be done. Since $L$ is full-rank, its column space spans the whole $\mathbb R^m$, any vectors in $\mathbb R^m$ can be linearly expressed by columns of $L$, so are columns of $Y$.
This also holds for general case that $L$ is any full-rank square matrix (no need to be lower triangular).
Am I right?

What about $Y=I$ and $Z=X$? Am I missing something?

Oh I forgot to exclude this trivial case, is it the only way to decompose $X$ in my question? I prefer $Y$ to be a dense symmetric matrix (not diagonal, at least).

$\def\ed{\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}}$If $\ Y\ $ is an $\ m\times m\ $ symmetric matrix of rank $\ m\ ,$  and $\ X=YZ\ ,$ then $\ Z=Y^{-1}X\ .$ Conversely, if $\ Y\ $ is any $\ m\times m\ $ symmetric matrix of rank $\ m\ $ and $\ Z\ed Y^{-1}X\ ,$ then $\ X=YZ\ .$ Is there something that I'm missing?


since the original post was modified, here $R=X$ and we have the desired $Y=S$ and $Z=Q$.

If you have a full rank matrix of the sort, set $A = R R^T$. $A \in S_m(\mathbb{R})$. Since $\ker R^T = (\operatorname{im} R)^\bot$, we deduce that $A$ is invertible.
Now for $X \in \mathbb{R}^m$, $X^TAX = (R^TX)^T(R^TX) \geq 0$, which means $A$ is definite positive. It thus admits a unique symmetric definite positive square root $S$.
We set $Q = S^{-1} R \in M_{m,n}(\mathbb R)$, it is of full rank. It verifies $QQ^T = I_m$ which means $Q^T$ is an isometry. Thus using a base decomposition fitting the orthogonal direct sum
$$R^n =  \operatorname{im} Q^T \oplus \ker Q$$
with arrival base corresponding to the $\operatorname{im} Q^T$ part, you will get a matrix of the form
$$\begin{pmatrix}
O & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
With $O$ orthogonal.
This is a weaker variant of the polar decomposition.

Do we know $R$ and set $A=RR^T$ or do we know $A$ and decompose it? Where is the symmetric matrix the OP is asking for?

@obareey why downvote before Checking by yourself, S is thé unique symmetric definite positivé square foot of $A$

Yes, but where does $A$ or $R$ comes from in the context of the question?

@obareey the question was edited since. It answered the original post here $R=X$
